# Kivy: drawing not updating when changing line points

Tags: python, python-2.7, drawing, kivy

I guess my question is pretty much summed up in the title.

I am using an update call (similar to the one in the Pong tutorial). Within this call I update the points of a line. Though I can check that the points are indeed being updated, the actual line drawing is not.

I'll put some of the code up here:

```
class GraphInterface(Widget): 
    node = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self, dt):
        for widget in self.children:
            if isinstance(widget, GraphEdge) and widget.collide_widget(self):
                widget.check_connection()

class GraphEdge(Widget):
    r = NumericProperty(1.0)
    #determines if edge has an attached node
    connected_point_0 = Property(False)
    connected_point_1 = Property(False)
    #provides details of the attached node
    connected_node_0 = Widget()
    connected_node_1 = Widget()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GraphEdge, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(self.r, 1, 1, 1)
            self.line = Line(points=[100, 200, 200, 200], width = 2.0, close = True)


    def snap_to_node(self, node):
       if self.collide_widget(node):
            if (self.connected_point_1 is False):
               print "collision"
                self.connected_point_1 = True
                self.connected_node_1 = node
                del self.line.points[-2:]
                self.line.points[-2:]+=node.center
                self.size = [math.sqrt(((self.line.points[0]-self.line.points[2])**2 + (self.line.points[1]-self.line.points[3])**2))]*2
                self.center = ((self.line.points[0]+self.line.points[2])/2,(self.line.points[1]+self.line.points[3])/2)
                return True
        pass
```

The idea is to check for collisions initially, and once a collision has been made, I attach the line to this node widget. The points are then update as I move the node around. However right now although the points are updated, the drawing of the line is not.

If you need anymore code or information please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
del self.line.points[-2:]
self.line.points[-2:]+=node.center
```

These lines bypass operations that set the property, so the VertexInstruction doesn't know anything has changed and doesn't redraw itself.

They're a bit strange anyway, it would be simpler to just write:

```
self.line.points = self.line.points[:-2] + node.center
```

This would also update the instruction graphics, because you set the property directly rather than only modifying the existing list.